# Pulling the same value out of a series of keys

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I'm trying to quickly pull out ‘value’ property from some objects using destructuring.. is there a simple way to get it from this? I think it might be possible with  some complicated destructuring thing i haven’t quite grocked.

I know I could use loops and such, but I'd like to make it a bit more elegant. I'm looking for a non-repetitive, ideally 1-2 line solution. I wanted to use a map, but that only works on an array...

```
formData = {
  name: {val: 'myName', key: 'value', etc: 'more data'}
  province: {val: 'myProvince', key: 'value', etc: 'more data'}
  dateOfBirth: {val: 'myBDAY!', key: 'value', etc: 'more data'}
}


//desired outcome:
{
  name: 'myName',
  province: 'myProvince',
  dateOfBirth: 'myBDAY!'
}


//attempt 1
let customer = { name, province, dateOfBirth} = formData; //hrm doesn't get me there
```

Comment: Where are you specifying that it should use the `val` property of each element when destructuring?

Comment: If you're using underscore or lodash then `pluck` it. Alternatively `Object.keys(formData).reduce(function(acc, key) { acc[key] = formData[key].val; return acc; }, {});`

Comment: @Barmar nowhere.. it was a bad 'try', but I couldn't think of how to do it nicely.

Comment: @JaredSmith Hmm! don't want to include lodash for one thing.. I'm trying to ES6 it

Answer (score 2):

Destructuring is used to assign multiple variables from different elements of an array or object, that's not what you're doing. You can just do:

```
let customer = { 
    name: formData.name.val, 
    province: formData.province.val,
    dateOfBirth: formData.dateOfBirth.val
}
```

If you don't want to list all the properties explicitly, just use a loop.

```
let customer = {};
for (var k of Object.keys(formData)) {
    customer[k] = formData[k].val;
}
```

Comment: That works alright, but there's an unwanted (at least by me) level of repetition (the actual code has 8 properties and is an extra level deep)

Comment: Then you may just want to do the `for-in` loop.

Comment: Since this is ES6, it'd be much safer to do `for (var k of Object.keys(formData)){` to avoid picking up enumerable props in the prototype chain.

Comment: I'm still not fluent in all the new ES6 features.

Answer (score 1):

A hard to read one-liner would be:

```
let customer = Object.keys(formData).reduce(
        (acc, key) => Object.assign(acc, {[key]: formData[key].val}), {});
```

to grab `.val` off every value in the object, and return a new object with the same keys.

That's basically the equivalent of:

```
let customers = {};
for (const key of Object.keys(formData)) customers[key] = formData[key].val;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you didn't like Barmar's answer, you can use a combination of `Object.keys` and the resulting array's `reduce` method:

```
let customer = Object.keys(formData).reduce(function(acc, key) {
    acc[key] = formData[key].val;
    return acc;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 1):

You said you wanted to use destructuring… so let's do that:

```
let customer = {};
for (let k in formData) ({[k]: {val: customer[k]}} = formData);
```

But really, avoid that, and use clear and readable property assignment instead :-)